# how to wait for FileOpenPicker in UWP/WinRT to display and get the selected file from user? (C++ code)

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt, winrt-async

I am new in UWP/WinRT!

I have this code:

```
void MainPage::processButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker;
        picker.ViewMode(winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
        picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".mp4");
        auto filename= picker.PickSingleFileAsync().GetResults();           
       
    }
```

When I run this code, I am getting this error during run time:

> A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call)
> was executed in test.exe.

Changing the code to this one:

```
void MainPage::processButton_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker;
        picker.ViewMode(winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
        picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".mp4");
        auto filename= picker.PickSingleFileAsync().GetResults();
        
    }
```

Generate the same error.

How can I wait for a picker to finish its job and return a file that I can open in my C++ UWp/WinRT?

Answer (score 1):

The diagnostic you get is raised when you attempt to call [`GetResults`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperation-1.getresults) on an [`IAsyncOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperation-1) that hasn't run to completion.

To get around this you'll want to asynchronously wait for the operation to complete. The most direct way is to use a coroutine. [Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency) has all the information you need.

You can apply this to your code by changing it to the following:

```cpp
IAsyncAction MainPage::processButton_Click(IInspectable sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::FileOpenPicker picker;
    picker.ViewMode(winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers::PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
    picker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".mp4");
    auto filename = co_await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
}
```

Make sure to change the signature from taking references to receiving arguments by value. If you don't things will break in ways that are entirely hard to diagnose.